# How to use VS2010 query designer in a solution?

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, designer

Well met!  I'm missing something about VS2010... I want to create a solution that let's me use the visual query designer to build queries against an SQL server, as I can when I right click the server in Server Explorer and select New Query.  However, I can't seem to save this sort of query.

If I go into Solution Explorer, I can create a new TSQL query, but I cannot use the visual designer.  ???

So, what am I missing?  I'm sure there is some reasonable and over-arching design paradigm that is just completely eluding me as to why the Solution Explorer and Server Explorer would be so disintegrated that I could not create a query in the one and save it as part of a solution.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Perhaps the tool you seek is SQL Server Management Studio, rather than Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

It's my understanding that SQL 2008 is built in to VS2010.  Therefore you shouldn't have to use SQL Server MS.